# Real Line: Topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Problem**

Given the real and positive line $V=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}_+$,

Regard product structures:
$$\pi^\lambda:V^\Lambda\to V:(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\mapsto x_\lambda$$

And characteristic properties:
$$\chi:\Omega\to V^\Lambda:\quad\chi^{-1}\left(\mathcal{T}V^\Lambda\right)\subseteq\mathcal{T}\Omega\iff(\pi^\lambda\circ\chi)^{-1}(\mathcal{T}V)\subseteq\mathcal{T}\Omega\quad(\lambda\in\Lambda)$$

Regard algebraic structures:
$$\alpha:V\times V\to V:(x,y)\mapsto x+y$$
$$\mu:V\times V\to V:(x,y)\mapsto xy$$

And impose continuity:
$$\alpha^{-1}(\mathcal{T}V)\subseteq\mathcal{T}(V\times V)$$
$$\mu^{-1}(\mathcal{T}V)\subseteq\mathcal{T}(V\times V)$$

Regard injection and projection:
$$\iota:\mathbb{R}_+\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto x$$
$$\pi:\mathbb{R}\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{R}_+:x\mapsto|x|$$

And characteristic properties:
$$\eta:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}_+:\quad\eta^{-1}(\mathcal{T}\mathbb{R}_+)\subseteq\mathcal{T}\Omega\iff(\iota\circ\eta)^{-1}(\mathcal{T}\mathbb{R})\subseteq\mathcal{T}\Omega$$
$$\vartheta:\mathbb{R}_+\to\Omega:\quad\vartheta^{-1}(\mathcal{T}\Omega)\subseteq\mathcal{T}\mathbb{R}_+\iff(\vartheta\circ\pi)^{-1}(\mathcal{T}\Omega)\subseteq\mathcal{T}\mathbb{R}$$

Moreover impose Hausdorff!

> Does this give euclidean topology?

**Application**

This is a lemma for: [Dual Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1354365/79762)

Comment: So far I got: The real line is a TVS. It has finite dimension. So it is (only?) isomorphic to euclidean real line. Also the positive line has fix topology then.

Comment: What is left: Does the modulus satisfy the characteristic property? And do multiplication and addition become continuous? *(Caution: It is different product!)*

Comment: So, for example, your last statement says that $\vartheta$ is continuous iff $\vartheta \circ \pi_+$ is continuous. Is that right? And do you believe it is true for the usual topologies?

Comment: @RobArthan: Yep that is the characteristic property. But I'm not sure wether this holds for the usual topologies. Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: @RobArthan: Note there was a typo. I meant: $\vartheta:\mathbb{R}_+\to\Omega$

Comment: @RobArthan: I could prove that part now: Exploit $(\iota_+)^{-1}(A)=A\cap\mathbb{R}_+$ and $(\pi_+)^{-1}(B)=B\cup(-B)$.

Comment: It is only left: Are addition and multiplication continuous over the positive line?

Comment: @RobArthan: I got the last part. :D

Comment: How do your conditions exclude the discrete topology?

Comment: @RobArthan: For the discrete topology it fails to be a TVS.

Comment: Yes, but why do your conditions imply that the structure is a topological vector space? And what is the field of scalars for that vector space?

Comment: @RobArthan: The field of scalars is the reals and by continuity of multiplication and addition the real line becomes by definition a TVS.

Comment: Addition and multiplication are continuous with respect to the discrete topology.

Comment: @RobArthan: Ou shi#: You're right. I'm sorry!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Meanwhile I got it.. :D*

**Product Topology**

For the product topologies:
$$\mathcal{T}V^\Lambda=\left\langle\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}(\pi^\lambda)^{-1}(\mathcal{T}V)\right\rangle$$

*(This result is independent!)*

**Real & Positive Line**

As it is Hausdorff TVS:*
$$\dim\mathbb{R}<\infty:\quad\mathcal{T}\mathbb{R}=\mathcal{T}\mathbb{R}_E$$

That gives rise to:
$$\mathcal{T}\mathbb{R}_+=\iota^{-1}(\mathcal{T}\mathbb{R}_E)$$

Hausdorff transfers as:
$$\iota(a)=\iota(a')\implies a=a'$$
*(This proves uniqueness!)*

**Injection & Projection**

As they are inverses:
$$\pi\circ\iota=\mathrm{id}_+:\quad\pi^{-1}(N)\in\mathcal{T}\mathbb{R}_E\implies N\in\iota^{-1}(\mathcal{T}\mathbb{R}_E)$$

Conversely they act as:
$$\iota^{-1}(A)=A\cap\mathbb{R}_+\quad\pi^{-1}(B)=B\cup(-B)$$

For nontrivials one has:
$$\mathbb{R}_+\in\mathcal{N}_a\mathbb{R}_E\quad(a\neq0)$$

So on neighborhood filters:
$$N\in\iota^{-1}(\mathcal{N}_a\mathbb{R}_E)\implies N=M\cap\mathbb{R}_+\in\mathcal{N}_a\mathbb{R}_E\\
\implies N\cup(-N)\in\mathcal{N}_a\mathbb{R}_E\implies\pi^{-1}(N)\in\mathcal{N}_a\mathbb{R}_E$$

For the trivial one has:
$$\mathcal{B}_0\mathbb{R}_E:=\{(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon):\varepsilon>0\}:\quad\langle\mathcal{B}_0\mathbb{R}_E\rangle=\mathcal{N}_0\mathbb{R}_E$$

So on neighborhood filter:
$$N\in\iota^{-1}(\mathcal{N}_0\mathbb{R}_E)\implies N=M\cap\mathbb{R}_+\supseteq[0,\varepsilon)\\
\implies N\cup(-N)\supseteq(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\implies\pi^{-1}(N)\in\mathcal{N}_0\mathbb{R}_E$$

*(So they are compatible!)*

**Addition & Multiplication**

Introduce the mapping:
$$\Phi:\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto(x,y)$$

It is continuous since:
$$\pi^\lambda\circ\Phi=\iota\circ\pi_+^\lambda\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R})$$

So the operations as well:
$$\iota\circ\alpha_+=\alpha\circ\Phi\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R})$$
$$\iota\circ\mu_+=\mu\circ\Phi\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R})$$

*(This proves existence!)*

**Here's flaw: See comments!*